# Deciphering using XOR?

Tags: xor

Given below is a cipher text.

```
b'37151032694744553d12220a0f584315517477520e2b3c226b5b1e150f5549120e5540230202360f0d20220a376c0067'
```

This is the program used to encryption.

```
def enc(f):
    e = base64.b64encode(f)
    z = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(e):
        z += [ e[i] ^ e[((i + 1) % len(e))]]
        i = i + 1
    c = binascii.hexlify(bytearray(z))
    return c
```

return c returns the cipher text. I need to find what was passed to enc() function. How do i do that.
I have already tried all the methods i could. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The result alone is not sufficient to find both operands.

`38` decimal is `100110` binary.

You can only tell that the operand are different in three bits and equal in all others.

Examples:

```
binary:                         decimal:
0100110 ^ 0000000 == 0100110    38 ^ 0  == 38

0000110 ^ 0100000 == 0100110     6 ^ 32 == 38

0000010 ^ 0100100 == 0100110     2 ^ 36 == 38

1100001 ^ 1000111 == 0100110    97 ^ 71 == 38
```